# Extract all elements from json array in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I have a table like:

```
id     Name   f_data
 1     Raj   {"review":"perfect", "tech":{"scalability":"complete", "backbonetech": ["satellite"], "lastmiletech":["Fiber","Wireless","DSL"] }}
```

I want to split f_data column to multiple columns. Expected result:

```
id     Name    review   scalability   backbonetech   lastmiletech
 1     Raj     perfect    complete      satellite   Fiber,wireless,DSL
```

when I tray split json column I couldn't remove the bracket. My output is:

```
 id  Name  review  scalability backbonetech   lastmiletech
 1  Raj   perfect complete   ["satellite"]   ["Fiber","wireless","DSL"]
```

I used this code:

```
SELECT id, Name,
   f_data->'review' ->>0 as review,
   f_data->'tech' ->> 'scalability' as scalability,
   f_data->'tech' ->> 'backbonetech' as backbonetech,
   f_data->'tech' ->> 'lastmiletech' as lastmileteck
from my_table;
```

Comment: Please consider following [these suggestions](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql/2977#2977).

Comment: I have no problem to split the Json column. After splitting, the results in some columns are in square bracket like ['Fiber', 'wireless','DSL']. I want to output be like Fiber, wireless, DSL without square bracket.

Comment: `f_data -> 'tech' -> 'backbonetech' ->> 0` maybe?

Comment: @ charlieface this is useful for selecting just one element. I want to return all element together like Fiber, wireless, DSl.

Comment: So you essentially want to turn a JSON array in a string with comma separated values? See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63802594/postgresql-print-json-array-as-csv) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68395242/turning-a-simple-json-array-to-a-csv-string-using-postgresql)